# pubsub message ingestion into Bigquery using data fusion

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-data-fusion

I've built a simple realtime pipeline to receive messages and attributes from pubsub subscription and wrangle them to keep only a few fields and load it to a BigQuery table. when deployed and run, the pipeline log says `Importing into table '<tablename>' from 0 paths; path[0] is '(empty)'; awaitCompletion: true`
I'm unable to understand why 0 paths and why all the records are going to errors when an error collector was setup. Is there a way to debug the wrangler stage better?
sample wrangler directives as below:

```
keep message,attributes
set-charset :message 'utf-8'
set-type :attributes string
parse-as-json :attributes 1
parse-as-json :message 5
keep attributes_page_url,attributes_cart_remove,attributes_page_title,attributes_transaction_complete,message_event_id,message_data_dom_domain,message_data_dom_title,message_data_dom_pathname,message_data_udo_ut_visitor_id
columns-replace s/^attributes_//g
columns-replace s/^message_//g
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see that there are 0 paths to load is that all records are causing errors during wrangling.

There are 2 ways in which you can capture these errors:

1. Configure the Wrangler stage to Fail Pipeline on error. This will show the exception/error in the logs.
2. Attach the Error output from the Wrangler stage to an Error Collector, and store the output in a File or GCS Sink. This allows you to capture the error message for each row. Configure the Error Collector as follows:

   1. Error Message Column Name = errorMsg
   2. Error Code Column Name = errorCode
   3. Error Emitter Node Name = invalidRecord

Comment: Thank you @Fernando Velasquez. I set the wrangler stage to fail on error and identified ```java.lang.Exception: Stage:Wrangler - Failing pipeline due to error : com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at line 1 column 12```. I read somewhere that this error could be due to invalid json received as part of pubsub attributes. tbh pubsub attributes is a map which I'm converting to string using a projection plugin. then parse-as-json in wrangler directives, even after this I see the mentioned malformed error. Is there a way around this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: The PubSub source sets the attributes as a Java Map<String, String>. You should be able to access this map and use a Jexl expression to get the value.

`set-column attributes_page_url attributes.get("page_url")` `set-column attributes_cart_remove attributes.get("cart_remove")`

And so on.

Comment: Thank you @Fernando Velasquez. It worked. Didn't know we can use Java getter in Jexl expression. wrangler documentation wasn't clear for me.

Comment: In this case, the `get()` expression works because attributes is an instance of `Map<String, String>` internally, so the jexl expression is able to execute the desired code. 

I'm glad to hear this worked!